# Android sliding tabs - set width of tabs programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

With my sliding tabs project, how can I programmatically set the width of the tabs so that they use the whole space of the sliding tab strip and are each equal in width size? I've tried using the code below but the tabs won't stretch as desired.

**SlidingTabLayout.java**

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    textView.setWidth(0);

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}
```

[image]

**Text weight error**

[image: text weight error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your method

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
textView.setWidth(size.x / count); // Where count is number of textviews
```

Also if you are supporting older version

Use this

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) 
{ 
    display.getSize(size); 
} 
else 
{ 
    size.set(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight()); 
}
```

Comment: I already had that line in my code but still nothing has changed.

Comment: After using that code block, I end up with this (a vanished strip). Please check the image above in the **Text weight error** section.

Comment: Can you check now. Last option from me.  :(

Comment: Not sure but there is a smaller way `setDistributeEvenly(true)`. You can try this too, if you want smaller code. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Where do I need to put that?

Comment: In the object of `SlidingTabLayout.java`

Comment: Its just where you are crating object of `SlidingTabLayout` class, call this method on that object. Try it when you have time. For now you can go with the other code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'll use the 5 lines of code. Have a nice day and here's your points.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Thanks, it works, but in tab last one is cut out text. do u have solution.

Comment: there is some extra space is used in tabs other than textview such as padding or margin. Change `textView.setWidth(size.x / count);` You need to change `size.x` to `size.x - totalPaddingOrMargin`

Answer (score 1):

In a update these you can now use,

`mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);`

within the onViewCeated,

More can be found [here.](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different problem, wherein I had to customize each of the tabs' width:

[image: Distribute Evenly]

I was using setDistributeEvenly function. Instead I needed to set each of the textviews' weight.

Add this variable on your **SlidingTabLayout.java**:

```
private int[] mTabWeights;
```

This method should set the tab weights:

```
public void setTabWeights(int[] weights){
        mTabWeights = weights;
    }
```

Look for the method **populateTabStrip()** and add an **else statement**:

```
if (mDistributeEvenly) {
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
     lp.width = 0;
     lp.weight = 1;

}else{
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
     lp.width = 0;
     lp.weight = mTabWeights[i];
}
```

You can refactor the code to make it cleaner. Here it is when used:

```
stNews = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.stNews);
stNews.setDistributeEvenly(false);
stNews.setTabWeights(new int[]{2,3,3});
```

Here's the end result:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you solve the problem for the new TabLayout? I face the same problem there.